# Multiple Camera Angle .ism and .ismc generation

Tags: streaming, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk, windows-media-encoder

I was trying to follow this sample of Microsoft's Multiple Camera Angles to use with Smooth Streaming client:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg134026(v=vs.95).aspx

The article doesn't indicate how to (or what did) generate the .ism file that they use in the sample.

My question is: how did they generate it (was it using Microsoft Expression Encoder)?

I have multiple files coming from different cameras and synchronized but I would like to use the picture-in-picture approach to see them both at the same time (not live).